# Query is Perfectly running in SQL Server Management Studion but not running through my Windows form Application (C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, winforms, linked-server

I am working on an application which will transfer the data from SQL SERVER to ORACLE. I have a linked object of oracle in sql server, I am inserting the data directly from sql server to oracle (as it is the requirement). The problem is that, my INSERT statement is giving me error

[image: Error I m getting when I execute the Query from Application]

when i execute it through my application, where it is running perfectly in SQL Server Management Studio. Here is the  INSERT Query:

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(ORACLE, 'SELECT * FROM DB.SQL_table') SELECT * FROM table where c_date = '20170316';
```

And here is my Code :

```
sql_command = new SqlCommand();
                sql_command.Connection = mssql;
                ora_command = new OracleCommand();
                ora_command.Connection = oracle;
                string sub_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table T WHERE T.C_Date = '" + date.Year + month + day + "'";
                sql_command.CommandText = sub_query;
                var sql_c = sql_command.ExecuteScalar();

                string ora_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SQL_table T WHERE T.C_Date = '" + date.Year + month + day + "'";
                ora_command.CommandText = ora_query;
                var ora_c = ora_command.ExecuteScalar();

                if (Convert.ToInt32(sql_c)!=Convert.ToInt32(ora_c))
                {
                    sql_command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(ORACLE, 'SELECT * FROM DB.SQL_table') SELECT * FROM table where c_date = '" + date.Year + month + day + "';";
                    var sql_count = sql_command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    if (Convert.ToInt32(sql_count) != 0)
                    {
                        Status = "Done Uploading Data.\n\nLast Updated on " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Status = "Some Error Occured, Please Check.\n\nLast Checked on " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Status = "No missing data found.\n\nLast Checked on " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                }
```

PS: If you need More Information, I am ready to provide.

Comment: Check `date.Year + month + day` value. Probably you pass a wrong value that return nothing ?

Comment: I suspected `DB.SQL_table` & `table` have different column count each other (more specifically, `SQL_table` has more/less column than `table`), hence it won't work. Can you provide column list of both tables then?

Comment: It seems like most of your code (before and after the query execution itself) is irrelevant to the problem. Is it possible to reduce it to the necessary minimum?

Comment: Check schema of your table.

Comment: what are the values in month and day ? Might there be a comma in there which would cause the database to think there is an extra field there ?

Comment: shouldn't it be date.Year+date.Month+ date.Day or date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")

Comment: Thank you so much everyone, it was the IDE problem. Restarting the IDE and Rebuilding the Solution solved my Problem. Thank you so much everyone for your response.